# Solo me retorna un registro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy empezando con Laravel y tengo problemas para obtener los resultados de una consulta en la hoja de laravel.

Desde una lista obtenida a través de una consulta a MySQL 'mysql', quiero verificar el nombre que tiene en otra tabla de otra base de datos 'tienda'.

Todo está bien, pero solo devuelve el último valor de la segunda consulta, no devuelve todos los valores de la consulta $ products con su nombre correspondiente obtenido en $ products_name.

Controlador

```
$productos = [
        'id' => $id
    ];

    $products = DB::connection('mysql')
                ->SELECT("SELECT * FROM promociones_product WHERE id_promo = $id", $productos);

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        $products_name = collect(DB::connection('tienda')
                ->table('ps_product_lang')
                ->where('id_product', $product->id_product)
                ->get(['name', 'id_product']));
    }

    return view('promociones-products')->with('promo', $products_name);
```

Blade

```
@foreach($promo as $product)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $product->id_product }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
                </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Necesito hacer una consulta en la base de datos 'mysql' y, con esos resultados, consultar su nombre en otra base de datos, y todos los valores están impresos en la pantalla.

Comment: tienes las consultas dentro de un loop, entonces en la variable `$products_name` se están pisando los resultados de las consultas y sólo queda el valor de la última consulta del loop

Comment: Gracias por tu rápida respuesta @porloscerros! Vale, entonces cambiando el código por este: `$promo = [];

        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            $promo [] = collect(DB::connection('tienda')
                    ->table('ps_product_lang')
                    ->where('id_product', $product->id_product)
                    ->get(['name', 'id_product']));
        }

        return view('promociones-products', compact('promo'));` debería funcionar, verdad??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro de que esto funcione, lo hice tratando de entender mas o menos por donde van tus queries... pero puedes probarlo, pues además de resolver lo que dices:

> no devuelve todos los valores de la consulta

evita que hagas consultas a DB dentro de un loop (lo cual no es recomendable)

```
$productos_ids = [ $id ];

$id_product = DB::connection('mysql')
                ->table('promociones_product')
                ->whereIn('id_promo', $productos_ids) // whereIn devuelve los que están dentro del array
                ->pluck('id_product'); // pluck devuelve una colección con solo el campo id_product

$productos_promo = DB::connection('tienda')
                ->table('ps_product_lang')
                ->whereIn('id_product', $id_product) // whereIn devuelve los que están dentro de $id_product
                ->get(['name', 'id_product']);


return view('promociones-products')->with('promo', $productos_promo);
```

Comment: Genial! Me funciona a la perfección! Es justo lo que buscaba! Muchisimas gracias!